# C++ multi-threading methods const class objects

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, vector, methods

I'm attempting to speed up a chunk of code with multi-threading for a project I've been working on. The error I keep getting is this: 
"error: invalid use of non-static member function"

I have attempted using std::ref() on all of my parameters. 
I've also looked at making the method I'm running on individual threads static, but I found that that would change too much of the code base.
I found a little on std::bind() it was less than helpful.
I did some research on p-threads and was told that they would be just as difficult to manage. This is my first large multi-threading project, but I have many working samples that I have been trying to implement in a similar fashion.
Any new ideas would be welcome. I am sure I'm doing something off in left field, I don't primarily code in C++.

Updated >>>
I've got it to compile now, but it's not doing much, I was informed that I need to implement a queue to handle the data going in, I'm going to attempt that now, just thought I would update this post. I will update again if/when I run into more problems, or solve it myself. Thank you all for the suggestions. I hope to be able to leave this here as an example for anyone who may run into the same problems in the future.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include "someclass.h"

void SomeClass::foo(const BigClass &a, int b, int c, double d, double e, unsigned int f, unsigned int g, unsigned int num_threads, std::vector<Chunk> p_vect)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> thread_vect;

    unsigned int thread_spread = g / num_threads;
    unsigned int new_g = f + thread_spread - 1;
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < num_threads; x++)
    {
        thread_vect.push_back(std::thread(SomeClass::bar, &a, std::ref(b), std::ref(c), std::ref(d), std::ref(e)));
        f += thread_spread;
        newg += thread_spread;
    }
    for (auto &t : thread_vect)
    {
        t.join();
    }
}

Chunk SomeClass::bar(const BigClass &a, int b, int c, double d, double e)
{
    BigClass my_a(a);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (int)moves.size(); i++)
    {
     BigClass tmp_a(a);
        Chunk tmp_p_data = this->baz(tmp_a, b, c + 1, d, e);
        if (tmp_p_data.utility < p_data.utility)
        {
            p_data.utility = tmp_p_data.utility;
            p_data.move = moves[i];
            p_data.move_ok = true;
            if (p_data.utility <= d)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (p_data.utility < e)
            {
                e = p_data.utility;
            }
        }
    }
    return p_data;
}
```

updated >>>

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include "someclass.h"

void SomeClass::foo(const BigClass &a, int b, int c, double d, double e, unsigned int f, unsigned int g, unsigned int num_threads, std::vector<Chunk> p_vect)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    unsigned int x;

    for (x = 0; x < max_threads; x++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&SomeClass::bar, this, std::ref(a), std::ref(b), std::ref(c), std::ref(d), std::ref(e)));
    }
    for (x = 0; x < max_threads; x++)
    {
        threads[x].join();
    }
}

Chunk SomeClass::bar(const BigClass &a, int b, int c, double d, double e)
{
    BigClass my_a(a);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (int)moves.size(); i++)
    {
     BigClass tmp_a(a);
        Chunk tmp_p_data = this->baz(tmp_a, b, c + 1, d, e);
        if (tmp_p_data.utility < p_data.utility)
        {
            p_data.utility = tmp_p_data.utility;
            p_data.move = moves[i];
            p_data.move_ok = true;
            if (p_data.utility <= d)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (p_data.utility < e)
            {
                e = p_data.utility;
            }
        }
    }
    return p_data;
}
```

I expect to be able to spawn multiple threads on the same method with different inputs at the roots of a large tree of data that I'm traversing.
Currently I'm compiling, but the program never finishes. It does spawn multiple threads, but I'm not currently handling the data correctly as of yet.
Each traversal can take from < 1 second to > 45 seconds depending on pruning. If I end up running > 20 seconds a branch, the project I'm working on will not meet the project requirements.

Comment: So… use `&` to get the pointer-to-member you need?  (This example is hardly minimal for this error!)

Comment: Have a look at how to construct a [mcve]. Include all neccesary code so that anyone can copy-paste this and compile it (with the same error you get). At the same time leave out anything that isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: SomeClass::foo will be blocking as you are joining in the member func itself.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! please note it's not a blog site so you can't keep updating your post with more problems. For each one you're supposed to ask a separate question, ideally with minimal and compilable example that reproduces the problem